# Can't make the OpenGL Render Active Viewport work on Rendered Shade mode

Tags: animation, opengl

I'm using the OpenGL Render Active Viewport to preview an animation, but even if I'm set the viewport shade to "Rendered", it switch the shade mode to "Solid". I can make it work with any other mode but the "Rendered" mode.
(I can set the Rendered mode in the viewport with no problems)
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Sucks no one told you but you need to click RenderLayer next to OpenGL Render Active Viewport button. Ez pz. Hope this helps anyone else who might have this problem.